# How can i do a redirect in beforeControllerAction() function from module in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I want to a redirect in this function. How can I do that?

I tried the following:

```
$this->owner->redirect(array("/myurl"));
Yii::app()-request->redirect('/myurl');
$this->redirect('/myurl');
```

none of them are working.

I tried with header('Location:myurl'); It works, but I don't want to use header in Yii php framework. Do you I have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect inside controller's action, use:

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/myurl');
```

`$this` is your controller.
And If you want to redirect in somewhere elese(for example in components or extensions), use:

```
Yii::app()->controller->redirect(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/myurl')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->redirect(Yii::App()->request->baseUrl.'/myurl');
```